# All the available RAM on the postgres node is cached

Tags: postgresql-9.4, postgresql-9.6

Postgres is running on an instance with 60GB RAM. Of which 15GB is allocated for shared_buffers. I understand that postgres caches the data in shared_buffers and the OS cache before writing it to disk.

59GB/60GB is cached and the node is left with 1GB free memory.
( confirmed from the output of free -gh)

Will this lead to any failures on Postgres?
What happens if the data grows and the node is left with no free memory?

Comment: It will start swapping and performance will degrade significantly

Comment: Increasing RAM is the only solution here? I don't think vertically scaling the RAM is the solution for this. Please let me know otherwise